# Incorrect output for if/elseif statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Within my submit button, the if/else if statement is not working properly for my correct/incorrect output.

For example, question:  where is Victoria?  Answer: British Columbi - Incorrect.  However if I answer: Alberta or British Columbia it is correct.   I don't understand the error.  The error occurs if I write the province incompletely, not if it's the wrong province.

How can I solve this?

Here's my code:

**Submit button code**

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    outputDegree.setText(null);
    if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(0))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);

    }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(1))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(2))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(3))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(4))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(5))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(6))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(7))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(8))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(9))) {         
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(10))) {         
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(11))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (inputAnswer.getText().equals(provinces.get(12))) {
     outputDegree.setText("Correct");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else {
       outputDegree.setText("Incorrect, try again!!");
       nextQuestion.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

**Displaying answer and possible answers (1 right, 3 wrong)**

```
private void nextQuestionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
   boolean trueOrFalse;

   outputTextQuestion.setText(null);
   outputTextQuestion.setText(setQuestions().toString());
   outputAnswers.setText(null);        
   inputAnswer.setText(null);       
   outputDegree.setText(null);

   clicked++;

   int buttonLimit = 4;

   if (clicked  <= buttonLimit) {


       int correctAnswer = -1;

        for (int x = 0; x < cities.size(); x++)
        {
            if (trueOrFalse = outputTextQuestion.getText().contains(cities.get(x)))
            {
                correctAnswer = x;
                break;
            }
        }
        randomAnswers = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        Collections.addAll(randomAnswers, correctAnswer);

        for (int x=0; x < 3; x++)
        {
           int r = correctAnswer;
           while (randomAnswers.contains(r))
            {
                r = ((int)(Math.random()*100))%cities.size();

            }
            Collections.addAll(randomAnswers, r);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(randomAnswers);
        outputAnswers.setText(null);

        for (int r=0; r<randomAnswers.size(); r++) {
             int hint = randomAnswers.get(r);
             outputAnswers.append(provinces.get(hint) + "\n");
        }
}

   else{
        nextQuestion.setEnabled(false);
        submitButton.setEnabled(false);
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Start new round");
        outputDegree.setText(null);


   }
```

I am also using ArrayLists such as cities, provinces, randomAnswers.  I just haven't shown my whole program because it's big.  If needed, I can.

I'm doing this in Netbeans, and this program is a GUI

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: try to use `switch-case`. it will make your code much simplier

Comment: @dehasi  But, it would still be comparing the same things?  Wouldn't it?

Comment: You're comparing the written answer to 13 entries of the `provinces` collection, so 'yes' it looks like you check if the written answer is somewhere in there and not if it the correct answer.

Comment: note that that code could be drastically simpified with a loop

Comment: You say you don't understand the error; what _is_ the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider using a loop to iterate your list instead of doing it manually. Imagine if you have 50 elements in provinces.

```
String answer = inputAnswer.getText();
boolean isCorrect = false;
for (String city : provinces) {
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
        outputDegree.setText("Correct");
        nextQuestion.setEnabled(true);
        isCorrect = true;
        break; // stops the loop if answer is correct
    }
}
if (!isCorrect) { //if there were no correct answers
    outputDegree.setText("Incorrect, try again!!");
     nextQuestion.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing which part of code is supposed to do what you seem to expect, where you expect a partial input to be a match, here are reasons:

- In the first method, you're using `equals()`. A partial match will never equal the full text.
- In the second method, you're using `contain()`, but reversed:
  `getText().contains(cities.get(x))`
  The partial text `bert` does not contain the full text `Alberta`. It's the other way, i.e. `Alberta` *contains* the text `bert`.

Answer (score 0):

In `submitButtonActionPerformed()` you are comparing `inputAnswer.getText()` with all the valid `provinces` - If it matches any of them you are setting `outputDegree.setText("Correct")` - Thus in your logic you interpret incorrect answer **ony if** the user input is not matching any of the provinces. You should think about this logic and correlate the question with user's answer in this API